# I want to print my query output without the column header and row no. fields

Tags: postgresql

The following is my query for a problem I am solving in postgreSQL but the output requires my answer to be without the column header and row number fields. How do I do it?

```
SELECT concat(firstName, ' ', SUBSTR(middleName,1,1) ,'. ' ,lastName, ' is from ', location, ' area')  FROM users
WHERE middleName LIKE 'K%';
```

The result:
[The output of my query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twdWq.png)

the expected result should be as follows
[The expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQSLD.png)

Comment: You have to change your client application not to print the column alias. This has nothing to do with PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html):

> `\t`
>
> Toggles the display of output column name headings and row count
> footer. This command is equivalent to `\pset tuples_only` and is
> provided for convenience.